# How to change an URL for webview dynamically using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, webview

I have an webview which load an URL(www.google.com). How can I change the webview to load an different url externally like by writing the url in firebase? Is it possible? I want an option to change the url externally without having to change the url in the activity an reinstall the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That simply just listen on url path that store in firebase like

```
private DatabaseReference mUrlReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("url")
ValueEventListener urlListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        // Web load here
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Url failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadUrl:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mUrlReference.addValueEventListener(urlListener);
```

Comment: Document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Can i see your database?

Comment: Note: you need to specific valid child that url have stored.