# Cursor doesn't change record

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-cursor

I'm working on application and I want to select from table all records where attribute type is equal to for example.

I used this query

```
val cursor = db.query(TableInfo2.TABLE_NAME, null, TableInfo2.TABLE_COLUMN_TYPE+" LIKE ?", arrayOf("2"), null, null, null)
```

in adapter in `getItemCount()` and it returns 2 which is true so it works
but when i try it in `onBindViewHolder` it doesn't move at all, it stays at only one record.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val cursor = db.query(TableInfo2.TABLE_NAME, null, TableInfo2.TABLE_COLUMN_TYPE+" LIKE ?", arrayOf("2"), null, null, null)
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            if(cursor.getString(1)=="option")
            {
                holder.imgM.setImageURI(cursor.getString(5).toUri())
                holder.imgM.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent = Intent(context, AddNewFood::class.java)
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                }
            }else{
                holder.imgM.setImageURI(cursor.getString(5).toUri())
                holder.imgM.setOnClickListener {
                    val dialog = DialogPopUp(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(5).toUri())
                    val manager = (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
                    dialog.show(manager, "customDialog")
                }
                holder.imgM.setOnLongClickListener(object: View.OnLongClickListener{
                    override fun onLongClick(p0: View?): Boolean {
                        MainActivity.position = position + 1
                        MainActivity.check2 = true
                        val intent = Intent(context, AddNewFood::class.java)
                        context.startActivity(intent)
                        return false
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Originally it was

```
val cursor = db.query(
            TableInfo2.TABLE_NAME, null, BaseColumns._ID + "=?", arrayOf(
                holder.adapterPosition.plus(
                    1
                ).toString()
            ), null, null, null
        )
```

if it's like this it returns all the records

I tried `cursor.moveToNext()` in many places with no result.

Comment: If you want to select all records, wouldn't you need a loop somewhere? something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8781231/880990

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes ```onBindViewHolder``` is executed 2 times because there are 2 items so it's already a loop

Comment: See: [How do I attach RecyclerView adapter from sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43012038/880990).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes didn't help but thanks for tunning in :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I GOT IT !
If someone needs it, I've added `cursor.moveToPosition(position)`
after first if statement

Comment: This should work, but is not very efficient, as it will execute the query for each view item. Okay, you have only 2 records, but if you had more, then you should load the data into a collection (in onViewCreating or whatever) and then take  them from the collection in onBindViewHolder.